# Почему doctrine не может проставить правильный id при создании записи в базу в postgresql?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony2, doctrine2

Доброго времени суток.

Есть две сущности и есть связь один к одному. Это users и user_info. Связал их вот так:

```
/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

// ...
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserInfo", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $information;


/**
 * UserInfo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_info")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserInfo
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="userInfo")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $user;
```

Добавляю данные так:

```
$user = $form->getData();
            $user->setCreated(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            $user->getInformation()->setBalance(0);
            $user->getInformation()->setRevShare(0);
            $user->getInformation()->setMessengerType('skype');

            $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
            $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());

            $user->setPassword($encoded);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
```

Суть в том, что у основной сущности (Users) id проставляется, а у User_info id устанавливает в null и PG отказывается такой запрос выполнять, дескать, id не может быть null , хотя, судя по профилировщику symfony, доктрина выполняет оба запроса:

```
SELECT NEXTVAL('users_id_seq');
SELECT NEXTVAL('user_info_id_seq');
```

В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 2):

Doc: [Saving Related Entities](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#saving-related-entities)

Видимо проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь достать объект Information оттуда, где его еще нет. Попробуйте сделать так, как в документации написано -сначала создать объект потом его добавить в связанный:

```
...
$information = new UserInfo();
$information->setBalance(0)
    ->setRevShare(0)
    ->setMessengerType('skype');
$user->setInformation($information);

/**
вместо
$user->getInformation()->setBalance(0);
$user->getInformation()->setRevShare(0);
$user->getInformation()->setMessengerType('skype');
**/
...
```

Comment: Объект information есть, я получаю его из формы. У меня в одной форме две связанные сущности. В mysql все отлично работает и добавляет сразу в две таблицы

Answer (score -4):

```
<?php

class User implements UserInterface 
{ 

    public function __construct()
    {
        .........
        $this->userInfo = new UserInfo();
    }
}
```